# Conditionally modify query based on parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query (something like a case statement which I can use and fix it)

```
select *
from mytable
where 1=1 
and (isNull(ID, 0) = 0 OR UtilityID IN (9,40))
```

I also want to add another statement

```
select *
from mytable
where 1=1 
and UtilityID NOT IN (9,40)
```

Everything is happening in a procedure, so want to use a variable like `declare @something` so if that is passed as `1`, use the first statement and the if `0` is passed, use the latter one.

Comment: the second statment is just after the and of the first statement, modified above

Answer (score 1):

While I appreciate the genius in Dale's answer I find this more readable:

```
IF @something = 0 
BEGIN
  select *
  from mytable
  where ID IS NULL OR ID = 0 OR UtilityID IN (9,40);
END
IF @something = 1
BEGIN
  select *
  from mytable
  where UtilityID NOT IN (9,40);
END
```

It's procedure code, so use IF to direct the control flow. Also expanded and simplified your where clauses

Comment: query is quite big, so using it two times makes no sense

Comment: @Seb, consider creating a view or table-valued function from the large query to avoid repetition, then you can do something like: `IF @something = 0 SELECT * FROM myview WHERE {ConditionA} ELSE SELECT * FROM myview WHERE {ConditionB}`. In general the IF/ELSE approach will yield more efficient query plans than `WHERE (@something = 0 AND {ConditionA}) OR (@something = 1 AND {ConditionB})`.

Comment: @seb to be fair, you *did* say "I have this query" and not "I have an enormous query but I've contrived this small example for this question" - we can only answer questions based on what you tell us :) I second the recommendation of creating a view /TVF  - it gives you a single place to modify the logic of the code and might be reusable elsewhere too

Comment: Erland discusses different techniques for [dynamic search conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your logic, ignoring the `1=1` (which does nothing) you want to only allow `id = 0` when `@something = 1`. This should do it:

```
declare @something bit = 0;

declare @mytable table (ID int, UtilityID int);

insert into @mytable (ID, UtilityID)
  select 0, 1 union all
  select 1, 2 union all
  select 2, 9 union all
  select 3, 40;

select *
from @mytable
where (
  (@something = 1 and (isnull(ID, 0) = 0 or UtilityID in (9,40)))
  or (@something = 0 and (UtilityID not in (9,40)))
);
```

A more performant approach for a larger query could be:

```
select *
from @mytable
where (@something = 1 and (isnull(ID, 0) = 0 or UtilityID in (9,40)))
union all
select *
from @mytable
where (@something = 0 and (UtilityID not in (9,40)));
```

PS: Hopefully your `ID` cannot ever by `null` - it should have a constraint on it.